# Template funtion returning an iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

i would like to make a reusable function that returns an iterator to make it easy to find the middle point of a container and need some help

fixed;

```
template <typename T> std::vector<int>::const_iterator middlepoint(std::vector<T> const& arr){
    auto temp = arr.begin() + arr.size() /  2;
    return temp;
}
```

the caller:

```
auto middle_point = middlepoint(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

fixed:

```
template <typename T>  int middlepoint(std::vector<T> const& arr){
    std::cout << "size: " << arr.size() << endl;
    auto middle_point = arr.begin() + (arr.size()/  2);
    int middle_element = middle_point - arr.begin();
    return middle_element;
}
```

caller:

```
int middle_element = middlepoint(arr);
```

error:

```
ambiguous
```

ambiguous, means you declared 2 functions with the same name, but different parameters.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I'm getting very different errors from this code...

Comment: Are there multiple overloaded `middlepoint`? How are they declared?

Comment: It seems strange to accept any kind of iterator for input but return a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` no matter what.

Comment: @Borgleader HackerRank.

Comment: @songyuanyao ya, i had some typo's-

Comment: @Nathan Pierson the function originated from another stack question and i modded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're taking the beginning and end iterators and dividing them by 2 to get the middle position. Iterators don't have a valid expression for division, so what you're doing won't work.

The best way I can think to implement this would be to use the size of the container divided by 2 as an offset from the beginning or the end (whichever works best for you). This way you wouldn't need to pass both iterators to the function.

```
auto mid = it.begin() + (arr.size() / 2);  original
return mid;
```

If you can't get the size of the container using the .size() method (which you should be able to because you have access to the iterators), you can create a helper function that cycles through and counts. That shouldn't be needed for your case though because you're using a vector.

Comment: thnx, i got that one fixed, updated the topic.
but how about the first one? to return an iterator.

Comment: return arr.begin() + (arr.size()/  2); that's all you need

Comment: yeah,i figured that also just a moment ago.
i have both working now